# Change the color of a list of buttons and save it?

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to implement a dual n back kind of game. So I have a list of buttons and then they will change the color randomly with the time(I intend to make it a darker blue). I wonder how to do it and how to save this state so I can compare the current darkened button with the previous ones. Here is my code as I'm already implementing the audio part of it:

```java
package com.example.dual;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.speech.tts.TextToSpeech;
import android.widget.Button;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import java.io.LineNumberInputStream;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Locale;
import java.util.Random;

public class Dual extends Activity implements Runnable {
    int clicksVisaoCorretos = 0;
    int clicksAudicaoCorretos = 0;
    int clicksVisaoOmitidos = 0;
    int clicksAudicaoOmitidos = 0;
    int clicksVisaoIncorretos = 0;
    int clicksAUdicaoIncorretos = 0;
    int nivel = 1;
    List<Button> listaBotoes = new ArrayList<Button>();

    String letras[] = {"P", "Q","R","T","X","Z","S","Y","U"};
    Random aleatorio = new Random();
    Button botaoPrimeiro;
    Button botaoSegundo;
    Button botaoTerceiro;
    Button botaoQuarto;
    Button botaoQuinto;
    Button botaoSexto;
    Button botaoSetimo;
    Button botaoOitavo;

    private TextToSpeech letrasFaladas;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle b) {
        super.onCreate(b);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_dual);
        botaoPrimeiro =(Button) findViewById(R.id.botaoUm);
        botaoSegundo =(Button) findViewById(R.id.botaoDois);
        botaoTerceiro = (Button) findViewById(R.id.botaoTres);
        botaoQuarto = (Button) findViewById(R.id.botaoQuatro);
        botaoQuinto = (Button) findViewById(R.id.botaoCinco);
        botaoSexto = (Button) findViewById(R.id.botaoSeis);
        botaoSetimo = (Button) findViewById(R.id.botaoSete);
        botaoOitavo = (Button) findViewById(R.id.botaoOito);
        listaBotoes.add(botaoPrimeiro);
        listaBotoes.add(botaoSegundo);
        listaBotoes.add(botaoTerceiro);
        listaBotoes.add(botaoQuarto);
        listaBotoes.add(botaoQuinto);
        listaBotoes.add(botaoSexto);
        listaBotoes.add(botaoSetimo);
        listaBotoes.add(botaoOitavo);
        botaoPrimeiro.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
        botaoSegundo.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
        botaoTerceiro.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
        botaoQuarto.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
        botaoQuinto.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
        botaoSexto.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
        botaoSetimo.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
        botaoOitavo.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
        Handler h = new Handler();
        h.postDelayed(this, 3000);
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        String letraAleatoria = (letras[aleatorio.nextInt(letras.length)]);
        for (int x = 0; x <= 12; x++) {

            letrasFaladas = new TextToSpeech(Dual.this, new TextToSpeech.OnInitListener() {
                @Override
                public void onInit(int i) {
                    if (i == TextToSpeech.SUCCESS) {
                        letrasFaladas.speak(letraAleatoria, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);
                        letrasFaladas.setLanguage(new Locale("pt", "BR"));
                    }
                }

            });
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need a darker blue shade and want to save that color in your project. You can simply do it by getting a hex code or by opening a color picker in color folder present in the resources. you can also name it and use it programmatically.

I have attached image for reference.
[image: color picker]

[image: color folder in values]

Then you can use it like this in your activity or fragment.

```
    ResoureCompat.getColor(getResources(),R.color.your_color,null)
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).